# How to create a function that detects if a word contains an e-character?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
word = raw_input("Enter word: ").count('e')

def has_no_e(word):
    for i in word:
        if i not in word:
            return True

print has_no_e(word)
```

Comment: You've assigned the variable `word` to be the number of lowercase E's in whatever the user types in. Thus, there's no need for a function, simply print `word > 0`.

Comment: `def has_no_e(aString): return 'e' not in aString`

Answer (score 0):

Python provides a membership operator that can be used with string.

The *in* operator return *True* if the first operand is contained within the second, and *False* otherwise.

So

```
>>> "b" in "aaa"
False
```

and

```
>>> "a" in "aaa"
True
```

In your case you can combine it with *not* negation and do something like this:

```
def has_no_e(word):
    char = 'e'
    return char not in word
```

Using this:

```
if has_no_e("word-e"):
    print "No e char in this word!"
else:
    print "This word has e character"
```